# Parent and Child in OOP

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose that we have two classes as bellow:

```
class Parent 
{
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public int ChildId {get; set;}
}
```

According to the above, which line is correct and why? and also which line is not correct and why?

- Parent p = new Child();
- Child c = new Parent();

**Update: I forget to inherit Child from Parent and I correct it!**

Comment: Neither, as Child doesn't inherit from Parent..

Comment: Did you try it? The warnings in your IDE should tell you the answer...

Comment: Inheritance isn't necessary here; it could be a "contains" relationship instead.

Comment: Looks like (borked) homework …

Comment: @Rawling - What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @DangerZone Just because one doesn't inherit from the other, doesn't mean that's the issue. This could be a parent and child in a school system, say. (Edit: or... that could be the issue...)

Comment: So even with the update my comment still stands, try it in your IDE and it will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is correct, second is not.

By definition, a Child will inherit all properties and methods of a Parent; however, Parent will not have all properties and/or methods of a Child, so the second statement wouldn't make sense:

```
class Parent 
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public void Eat { ... }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public void Play { ... }
}

Parent child = new Child();
child.Eat(); // this makes sense since this is common functionality

Child parent = new Parent();
parent.Play() // this does not make sense since a Parent doesn't know hot to play
```